# "Cannot find symbol: method damage(int)"

Tags: java, methods

I'm getting the following error:

> C:\Users\[USER]\Desktop\Java\TextAdventure\TextAdventure.java:39: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol  : method damage(int)
>
> location: class TextAdventure
>
> out.println("you do "+damage(pS)+" damage");

```
public class TextAdventure{
    public static int pS=0;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner reader=new Scanner(in);
        while((pS>10) || (pS<1)){
            out.println("\nEnter your strength attribute:   ");
            pS=reader.nextInt();
        }//ask for strength, repeat if not between 1 and 10
        out.println("you do "+damage(pS)+" damage");
```

The `RandomDamage` class with the `damage(int)` method is as follows:

```
public class RandomDamage {
    public static int damage(int x){
        int dMult=(int)(Math.random()*11);
        return dMult*x;
    }
}
```

I'm using JCreator LE's "project" thing for the first time, so I'm just assuming that I don't need to deal with creating different packages or anything. I have `RandomDamage` and `TextAdventure` under "Package Default"

Comment: `damage` is a static method. You can access it by prefixing the method name with the class name that implement this method, i.e `RandomDamage.damage(pS)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the class.

```
out.println("you do "+ RandomDamage.damage(pS)+" damage");
```

If you don't, it will look for a method `damage(int)` inside your current class, `TextAdventure`.

Comment: So when is creating a separate package necessary/suggested?

Comment: packages are really used to structure your project, create a folder when you want it (or in specific cases: want to restrict access to package-private). Do you perhaps mean `class` instead of `package`?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know how `package`s work and I thought that I needed to use one for this.

Comment: packages are really just folders where you store your files. Aside from the package-private access modifier, there is nothing that a package will do for you. It certainly hasn't got anything to do with your code.